# Prove: If $|a_n|$ doesn't converge to $\infty$ then $a_n$ must have a finite partial limit.

Tags: calculus, limits

Prove: If $|a_n|$ doesn't converges to $\infty$ then $a_n$ must have a finite partial  limit.

My thoughts:
if $|a_n|$ doesn't converges to $\infty$ there must be two other posibilities:

1. $|a_n|$ converges to a finite number,  $L$
2. $|a_n|$ doesn't have a limit at all (neither finite, nor $\infty$)

for option #1, we can infer $a_n$ is bounded by $L$ and has a converges parital limit (by BW Theorem).

**EDIT:**
The correct demand is to prove $a_n$ has a finite partial limit.
for option #1 I proved it using BW Theorem.
Now I need to prove $a_n$ has a partial finite limit for option #2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it doesn't converge to infinity then it must have a bounded subsequence(if it had no bounded subsequence, it would converge to infinity), this bounded subsequence then has a convergent subsequence, which itself is a subsequence of the original sequence.

Comment: Oh snap. I had to think about it

Comment: (This depends on how you define that a sequence converges to infinity. What you have is that if $a_n$ is unbounded, then it has a subsequence that converges to either $\infty$ or $-\infty$.)

Comment: @mathematician How do you go to rigorously prove that ?

Comment: $|a_n|\rightarrow\infty$ means for every $M>0$ there exists $N$ s.t. $n\geq N \Rightarrow |a_N|>M$.  So if it doesn't converge to infinity, there exists $M$ s.t. for all $N$ there exists $n>N$ with $|a_n|<M$.  The bounded subsequence is the $a_n$'s you get when taking different values for $N$.

Answer (score 2):

We have $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = L$ if and only if $\liminf_{n\to \infty} a_n = \limsup_{n\to \infty} a_n =L$. Here $L$ can be finite or infinite. If $L=\infty$, we have something stronger and conclude $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = L$ if and only if $\liminf_{n \to \infty} a_n = L$. It is enough to use facts about the liminf.

Answer (score 1):

This is basically the same answer as mathematician's:

For each integer $m$ we define

$$A_m:= \{ n | a_n \in [m,m+1) \} \,.$$

If all $A_m$ are finite, then it is easy to prove that 
$$\lim_n |a_n| =\infty \,.$$
Indeed, for each positive integer $M$ we have
$$|a_n| >M$$if and only if 
$n$ is not in the finite set  $\cup_{k=-M}^m A_k$. In particular, with $j$ being the largest element in this set we have
$$n > j \Rightarrow |a_n| >M \,.$$

Thus, some $A_m$ must be infinite. This $A_m$ defines a bounded subsequence, and hence we can find a subsequence of this which is convergent.

Comment: But it's given that this is not true :$\lim_n |a_n| = \infty $.

Also, I don't see how this is the same as mathematician's answer. Is this $A_m$ a subsequence of $a_n$?

Answer (score 0):

Let $a_n=(-1)^n$. Then $|a_n|$ converges to $1$ but $a_n$ does not converge.

Comment: Oops. it's **partial finite** limit and not finite limit.